# Template deduction failure of template of template (with inheritance in-between), is there a better way ?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++14, template-argument-deduction

### The problem

I had the following scheme in my code,

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct A {};

template <class T>
struct Z {};

template <class T, class U>
struct B : A<T>, Z<U> {};

template <class T>
struct C : B<T, T> {};

template <class T>
void foo(const std::shared_ptr<A<T>>& a)
{
    std::cout << "HI !" << std::endl;    
}

int main()
{    
    auto c = std::make_shared<C<char>>();

    foo(c);

    return 0; 
}
```

But the compiler could not substitute the template parameters properly:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:26:10: error: no matching function for call to 'foo(std::shared_ptr<C<char> >&)'
     foo(c);
          ^
main.cpp:17:6: note: candidate: template<class T> void foo(const std::shared_ptr<A<T> >&)
 void foo(const std::shared_ptr<A<T>>& a)
      ^~~
main.cpp:17:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:26:10: note:   mismatched types 'A<T>' and 'C<char>'
     foo(c);
          ^
```

### The fix

So I changed `foo` to this:

```
template <class T, template <class> class U>
void foo(const std::shared_ptr<U<T>>& a)
{
    std::cout << "HI !" << std::endl;    
}
```

### A better way ?

It works, but it doesn't feel right as the template constraints on the types are now really loose which usually end up into more obfuscated error message.

Is there a better way to handle these kind of template deduction failures ?

### Play with the example on Coliru

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4ebc14105c184df

Comment: As to why: user-defined conversions are not considered during template parameter deduction. Passing `shared_ptr<Derived>` for a parameter of type `shared_ptr<Base>` requires such a conversion. You could write `foo(std::static_pointer_cast<A<char>>(c));`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks. Is this "by design" then ? Do you have an idea as to why such conversions are not considered ?

Comment: Let's say you have `template <typename T> void f(A<T>);` and you call it with `f(seeminglyUnrelated);` To make this work, the compiler would have to try every single type `T` in existence, in hopes that `seeminglyUnrelated` might have a user-defined conversion to `A<T>`. Or alternatively, try every possible user-defined conversion sequence that could possibly apply to `seeminglyUnrelated`, in hopes that one (and only one) of them might produce a type that looks like `A<U>` for some U. Neither is practicable, and so compilers are not required to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way.  You can choose to constrain the template manually with a bit of template metaprogramming so that only pointer types (can be extended to work with all sorts of pointer types, but only works with both `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` in this case (actually with all smart pointer types that have an `element_type` type alias)) of derived classes can be used.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

namespace {

    /**
     * Get the template type of a template template type
     */
    template <typename T>
    struct GetType;
    template <typename T, template <typename...> class TT>
    struct GetType<TT<T>> {
        using type = T;
    };
} // namespace <anonymous>

template <class T>
struct A {};

template <class T>
struct Z {};

template <class T, class U>
struct B : A<T>, Z<U> {};

template <class T>
struct C : B<T, T> {};

template <class T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<
    A<typename GetType<typename std::decay_t<T>::element_type>::type>,
    typename std::decay_t<T>::element_type>::value>* = nullptr>
void foo(const T&)
{
    std::cout << "HI !" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    auto c = std::make_shared<C<char>>();
    auto c_uptr = std::make_unique<C<char>>();

    foo(c);
    foo(c_uptr);

    return 0;
}
```

This will now work both with `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`.  You can chose to make it more general by checking the type of pointer contained (`element_type` in the example) by using `decltype` with `.get()` on the smart pointer, and make a trait that detects if the pointer passed is a primitive pointer and if so just uses the type itself.  But you get the point.

Comment: Thanks ! I am not used to these SFINAE's enable_if/decay horrific combos, but if you take the time it makes almost sense. ;)

Comment: @matovitch let me know if you would like me to explain any of what I have in the code above to you!

Answer (score 1):

I propose a little improvement of your `foo` (the template template one) where the class receive a list of template type parameter; with SFINAE can activated only if the `C<T0, Ts...>` class is a derived class of `A<T0>`.

```
template <template <typename...> class C, typename T0, typename ... Ts>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<A<T0>, C<T0, Ts...>>::value>::type
   foo (const std::shared_ptr<C<T0, Ts...>>& a)
 { std::cout << "HI !" << std::endl; }
```

So you can call `foo()` with `A<T>`, `B<T, U>` and `C<T>` but not with `Z<T>` or (by example) `std::vector<T>`

The following is a full compilable example

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct A {};

template <typename T>
struct Z {};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct B : A<T>, Z<U> {};

template <typename T>
struct C : B<T, T> {};

template <template <typename...> class C, typename T0, typename ... Ts>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<A<T0>, C<T0, Ts...>>::value>::type
   foo (const std::shared_ptr<C<T0, Ts...>>& a)
 { std::cout << "HI !" << std::endl; }

int main ()
 {    
   foo(std::make_shared<A<char>>());
   foo(std::make_shared<B<char, long>>());
   foo(std::make_shared<C<char>>());
   // foo(std::make_shared<Z<char>>());           // compilation error
   // foo(std::make_shared<std::vector<char>>()); // compilation error
 }
```

Comment: I didn't need the variadicity in my case but thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you don't need to transfer ownership, so you should prefer to pass argument by const reference, and then it works as expected:

```
template <class T>
void foo(const A<T>& a)
{
    std::cout << "HI !" << std::endl;    
}

int main()
{    
    auto c = std::make_shared<C<char>>();

    foo(*c);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3de009d804c40e3d)

If you really need to pass `shared_ptr`, see the other answer.